# How to get the combined bounds of multiple UI image in a canvas?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, bounds

I'm trying to get the bounds of multiple ui images inside a canvas. I'm using this code:

```
Bounds bounds = new Bounds(imageList[0].transform.position, Vector3.zero);
for (int i = 0; i < imageList.Count; i++)
{
    bounds.Encapsulate(imageList[i].transform.position);
}
```

But if I have two images, the bound will start and ends in the middle of each image. This code is working when using a gameobject cube, sphere etc. but different result when using UI.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [`RectTransform.GetWorldCorners`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/RectTransform.GetWorldCorners.html) in order to get the 4 corners of each Image in word coordinates.

Then you can iterate over them and use [`Vector3.Min`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.Min.html) and [`Vector3.Max`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.Max.html) to calculate the minimum and maximum of all corners of all images.

And finally use [`Bounds.SetMinMax`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Bounds.SetMinMax.html) in order to create a bounding box using this minimum and maximum.

```
public class Example : MonoBehaviour
{
    public List<Image> imageList = new List<Image>();

    private void OnDrawGizmos()
    {
        var min = Vector3.positiveInfinity;
        var max = Vector3.negativeInfinity;

        foreach (var image in imageList)
        {
            if(!image) continue;

            // Get the 4 corners in world coordinates
            var v = new Vector3[4];
            image.rectTransform.GetWorldCorners(v);

            // update min and max
            foreach (var vector3 in v)
            {
                min = Vector3.Min(min, vector3);
                max = Vector3.Max(max, vector3);
            }
        }

        // create the bounds
        var bounds = new Bounds();
        bounds.SetMinMax(min, max);

        Gizmos.color = Color.red;
        Gizmos.DrawWireCube(bounds.center, bounds.size);
    }
}
```

---

Note: This bounding box will be world aligned with the global XYZ axis (as was your original attempt).

---

[image]

Answer (score 1):

1. Use [RectTransform.GetWorldCorners](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/RectTransform.GetWorldCorners.html) to get all corners of the images.
2. Find the minimal and maximal points.
3. Use [Bounds.SetMinMax](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Bounds.SetMinMax.html) to get the bounds.